# How to tell redis has gone away using redis-rb gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm using the gem [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) to build some Ruby on Rails apps that are using [redis](http://redis.io/).

I'd like to build in some logic to periodically check to see the redis instance I'm connected to has gone away.

What's the lowest overhead, fastest way of doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a [ping](http://redis.io/commands/ping) to the server by doing `redis.ping`.